# Dynamic generation of web form by client

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, drag-and-drop, client-side

I want to know the best way to implement a functionality, i.e., dynamic generation of web form on the client side by the user on my PHP web application? Also is there any readymade code or any API availale for it? Drag n Drop interface would be icing on the cake.

Comment: You could try jquery http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ with `ajax` to post the result to you php script

Comment: ok, that given. now how to implement this functionality in the least complicated way. can you shed some light on it?

Comment: It's explained in detail here : http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 1):

You could try jquery [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable) with ajax to post the result to you php script. 
It's explained in detail [here](http://webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php).